# PROCMAIL:: How do I get a perl script to execute AFTER having the mail delivered to the MBox

Tags: perl, email, procmail

I'm on a Red Hat installation. 
What I'm running into is that:

1. The perl script looks into the mailbox using Modules to look for message #0 or the delieved mail but it isn't there yet.
2. If I make a COPY of the mail using the C flag I still get the same response that it does not deliver it to the mailbox.

So what I need to know is a procmail recipe which delivers it to the mailbox then fires the script to process the delivered email.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: It may help to show the recipe that you currently have. Especially since you mention using a non-existent `C` flag (you probably meant `c`, but flags are case sensitive). Also, why to you need to have the perl script read the the message from the mbox file, it would likely work much better to simply deliver the message to the perl script.

Comment: I'm using the MAIL::BOX module to do the processing. It calls from the MBox mailbox. And yes I mean "c" lowercase

Comment: What @qqx said: you really should change your Perl script to read a single message on standard input, rather than write to the mbox and then parse it out of there again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I noted in a comment above, this seems like a bad way to do this.  But, you 
should be able to use something like:

```
:0c:
* Whatever condition
/path/to/mbox

  :0ahi
  | /path/to/perl/script
```

or equivalently

```
:0
* whatever condition
{
  :0c:
  /path/to/mbox
  :0ahi
  | /path/to/perl/script
}
```

The first recipe will cause the message to be delivered to the mbox file, but 
because the `c` flag is used processing will continue after that recipe.  The 
`a` flag on the following recipe specifies that it will only be used if the 
preceding recipe was used and completed successfully.

The `h` flag on that recipe specifies that only the headers should be sent to 
the perl script.  This probably won't affect it, since you say that it's 
getting the message from the mbox file rather than from the pipe; but it does 
reduce the amount of data that needs to be sent over the pipe.

The `i` flag specifies that procmail shouldn't complain if it can't send 
everything to the script.  Since the script likely isn't reading from its 
standard input, it's possible that the pipe buffers would fill up causing 
procmail to receive a write error; although this is very unlikely to happen 
when sending only the headers of the message.

If you really *need* to use the Mail::Box family of modules for processing the 
messages, rather than something that could parse a message from the standard 
input, I'd suggest that you at least use a Maildir mail box rather than mbox. 
There is no real specification for the mbox format, and there are many 
different interpretations of how it should work.  The differences tend to be 
subtle, so things could seem to be working fine until you receive a message 
which happens to trigger an incompatibility between different implementations 
(such as having a line starting with `From`).  That's not even getting into 
the issues with locking of mbox files.

Comment: I edited the question to include an alternative with braces which is IMHO more idiomatic.  I would have posted it as a comment otherwise, but you can't get proper code formatting here.

Comment: @tripleee Your alternative was **not** equivalent. It would have been equivalent to using the `A` flag on the second recipe in my original. But since I'd instead used `a` that needs to be carried over into your version. I've edited it to reflect that.

Answer (score -1):

So I was able to come up with the simple but although probably not the best answer. Since I have control over when the emails are coming in I decided to remove the lock on the process and it worked fine.

So without the second colon and the "c" option it now runs the script and can see the email in the mailbox.

Whew...what a pain...two days wasted on a simple solution.

Comment: Removing a lock sounds like a horrible solution. Mbox files are very vulnerable to simultaneous writers, and so locking should always be used when dealing with them. Even if you have complete control over when messages are delivered can you be sure that something won't change that later?

Comment: but if I can't get the perl script to fire AFTER it writes to the Mbox it is the only solution I have.